# Image map in bootstrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<img width="1085" height="366" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img921/8537/rkkTLj.png" class="hotspots-image" usemap="#hotspots-image-1415" data-event-trigger="click" data-highlight-color="" data-highlight-opacity="" data-highlight-border-color="" data-highlight-border-width="" data-highlight-border-opacity="" data-no-lazy="1">
```

[View js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hasmukhmistry/vnybxuLs/)

I have used two image maps,and arranged them in tabs.. First image map uses the picture(mounted on wall) area as hyper link, Second is uses that television on table.. Problem is, First image map works good. But second does not.. How can i overcome to this?

Comment: Did it work with my coordinates?

Comment: are you still alive? please give some feedback if i was helpful !

Answer (score 1):

Your coordinates on the 2nd image are wrong! 
The coords for the Television are: 319,267,321,312,373,307,368,265

Comment: This was useful , But these coordinates were generated dynamically.. And i figured out what was the problem..euro-monde.com , check PRESUPUESTO ONLINE here.. thanks for your help..